# yii2 ActiveForm with related data

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In my mysql database exists a articleID as AI PK and a articleNumber, which can be edited by the user.

The Problem:

In a yii2 ActiveForm, I want to let the user enter the articleNumber, while saving the articleID in the background.

So far, I created several models with relations.

I've got it working in my GridView:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'article.details.articleNumber',
            'label' => 'ArtNr.',
        ],
    ]
]);
```

In my create/edit form this does not work for me:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'article.details.articleNumber')->textInput() ?>
```

I'm new in creating yii2 applications and couldn't find anything in the documentation.
Am I using the wrong way to archive my goal or is there a trick to manage this?

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multiple model form here. i.e. in your form, you need to pass two models, one for your articleNumber, and another model of your relational table for article details.

You can refer following link for example : http://blog.dedikisme.com/blog/2014/10/13/yii2-building-a-single-form-with-multiple-models

Comment: I don't think this example would work. In my case, I want to add a new supplier order with a related article. In the supplier orders table I save the articleID, but the user should enter the articlenumber.